# Removing the second question mark from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

An external app calls my website with the following URL:
http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?route=checkout/success?ref=56

which is obviously wrong (since it has 2 questionmarks).

How can I write an .htaccess rewrite rule to convert the second questionmark to ambersand (&) ? (http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?route=checkout/success&ref=56)

I have tried this but it does not work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \? \& [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after some research, I have come up with this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?\?ref=(.*)&?(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1&ref=%2%3 [L]
```

I do not know if it's the best but it works for sure

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /(.*)?(.*)?ref=(.*)$ /$1?$2&ref=$3  [R]
  RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteLog "/var/log/rewrite.log"
```

must admit I have not seen it work on my end but it should be nearly there - enabled rewrite log so it can be debugged easier

Comment: thank you, but the `RewriteRule` could not capture the query string for some reason...